# IsNumeric Time value problem

Tags: sql-server

Table1

```
Time

10:00:00
12:00:00
Absent
14:00:00
Holiday
...,
```

Time column Datatype is varchar

I want to check the time column value is numeric then 'Present'

Tried Query

```
Select case when isnumeric(time) then 'Present' else time end as time from table1
```

Showing error in 'then'

How to modify my query according to my requirement

Need Query Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [ISDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx)

> Returns 1 if the expression is a valid
>   date, time, or datetime value;
>   otherwise, 0.

Something like

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
    [Time] VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '10:00:00' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '12:00:00' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'Absent' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT '14:00:00' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'Holiday'

SELECT  *,
        ISDATE(Time),
        case when ISDATE(time) != 0 then 'Present' else time end
FROM    @Table
```